The problem with sending a query to OpenAI
I am having trouble getting my Discord chatbot to send a query to OpenAI to generate a response. The OpenAI API key always shows a status of never being used, even though the query is supposed to be sent using this key, but it's not happening. Simply, the OpenAI API key wouldn't be used in the query.
I tried using global variables and it didn't work, adding attributes to functions with the API key also didn't work, updating the OpenAI library in Python, following error instructions but fixing one error led to another, searching for information on this topic on the internet, and now seeking help here
Script is here:
import os
import random
import discord
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import time

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Ustawienia bota i API
setTOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
setOPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']
print(f"Klucz openai: {setOPENAI_API_KEY}") # Sprawdzenie czy klucz się prawidłowo wczytał do kodu (Po naprawie usuń to)

# Zapis danych zmiennych takich jak ID użytkowników i ID kanałów
UserID = os.environ['userID']
ChannelID = os.environ['channel1ID']
ownerID = os.environ['ownerID']
setUserID = int(UserID)
setChannelID = int(ChannelID)

# Inicjalizacja klienta Discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.presences = True  # Wymagane do obsługi aktualizacji obecności
intents.messages = True  # Wymagane do obsługi wiadomości

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


# Konfiguracja ponownych prób i opóźnień
MAX_RETRIES = 1
RETRY_DELAY = 2  # Opóźnienie w sekundach

# Funkcja pomocnicza do obsługi zapytań HTTP
def make_request_with_retries(url, headers, data, max_retries, retry_delay):
    retries = 0
    while retries < max_retries:
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            if e.response.status_code in [429, 500, 502, 503, 504]:
                logging.warning(f"Temporary error {e.response.status_code}. Retrying in {retry_delay} seconds...")
                time.sleep(retry_delay)
                retries += 1
            else:
                raise e
    raise Exception(f"Max retries exceeded for {url}.")

# Funkcja do generowania odpowiedzi za pomocą OpenAI
def generate_response(prompt):
    try:
        retries = 0
        while retries < MAX_RETRIES:
            try:
                logging.info(f"Calling OpenAI API with prompt: {prompt}")
                
                # Logowanie klucza API
                logging.debug(f"Using OpenAI API Key: {setOPENAI_API_KEY}")
                
                # Wysłanie zapytania do API OpenAI
                headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': f'Bearer {setOPENAI_API_KEY}',
                }
                data = {
                    'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
                    'messages': [
                        {'role': 'user', 'content': prompt}
                    ]
                }
                response = requests.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', headers=headers, json=data)
                response.raise_for_status()  # Podnosi wyjątek w przypadku niepowodzenia żądania
                
                # Pobranie wygenerowanej odpowiedzi
                result = response.json()
                generated_text = result['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()
                response = str(generated_text)
                
                logging.info(f"OpenAI API response: {generated_text}")
                logging.info(f"OpenAI API response: {response}")
                return response

            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                if e.response.status_code == 429:
                    logging.warning("Rate limit exceeded. Retrying in 2 seconds...")
                    time.sleep(RETRY_DELAY)
                    retries += 1
                else:
                    raise e
        raise Exception("Max retries exceeded for OpenAI API requests.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in generate_response: {e}")
        return f"Błąd: Nie udało się wygenerować odpowiedzi.\n\nInformacje o błędzie: \n```\n{e}\n```"

# Funkcja do generowania odpowiedzi na obraz za pomocą OpenAI
def generate_image_response(image_url):
    try:
        # Logowanie klucza API
        logging.debug(f"Using OpenAI API Key: {setOPENAI_API_KEY}")
        
        # Wysłanie zapytania do API OpenAI o zawartość obrazu
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {setOPENAI_API_KEY}',
        }
        data = {
            'model': 'image-alpha-001',
            'image': image_url,
        }
        response = requests.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations', headers=headers, json=data)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Podnosi wyjątek w przypadku niepowodzenia żądania

        # Pobranie wygenerowanej odpowiedzi
        result = response.json()
        if 'data' in result and result['data']:
            generated_text = result['data'][0]['text'].strip()
            logging.info(f"OpenAI API image response: {generated_text}")
            return generated_text
        else:
            raise Exception("Image processing failed or returned no data.")
            
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in generate_image_response: {e}")
        return "Błąd: Obraz jest zbyt niskiej jakości lub zbyt mały."
    

# Eventy bota
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Zalogowano jako {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignorowanie wiadomości wysłanych przez samego siebie
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Sprawdzenie, czy wiadomość pochodzi od określonego użytkownika
    elif message.author.id == setUserID:
        try:
            if message.attachments:
                # Obsługa obrazów
                image_url = message.attachments[0].url
                response = generate_image_response(image_url)
            else:
                # Generowanie odpowiedzi za pomocą OpenAI
                response = generate_response(message.content)
            
            # Odpowiedź na wiadomość na tym samym kanale (serwer lub prywatna wiadomość)
            await message.channel.send(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{e}")
            responseList = ["Witaj", "Siema", "Elo", "Pa", "Nara", "Do widzenia", "Dobranoc", "Dzień dobry", "Znamy się?", "Nie Wiem",
                        "Kto Ty?", "Co tam u ciebie?", "Jesteś nie miły ", "Nie kłam", "Nie okłamiesz mnie", "LALALALA nie słucham Cię.",
                        "Co się stało?", "Dlaczego?", "Chyba Ty!", "Nie bo ja", "Nie bo ty", "Ta na pewno", "Uważaj bo ci uwierzę!",
                        "Jak się masz?", "Co nowego?", "Miłego dnia!", "Dzięki", "Proszę", "Przepraszam", "Cześć", "Hej", "Do zobaczenia", 
                        "Nie mam pojęcia", "To interesujące", "Naprawdę?", "Czemu nie?", "Pewnie", "Okej", "No to super!", "Zgadza się",
                        "Jasne", "Dokładnie", "To zależy", "Jak chcesz", "Może później", "Zaraz wracam", "Na pewno nie!", "Masz rację", 
                        "Dobra", "Jak najbardziej", "Serio?", "Nie zgadzam się", "Bez wątpienia", "Nie wiem co powiedzieć", "Świetnie!",
                        "Trzymaj się", "Do usłyszenia", "Nie sądzę", "Zdecydowanie nie", "Chwilka", "Moment", "Masz ochotę?", "Pomyśl o tym", 
                        "Jasne że tak", "To nie jest takie proste", "Dlaczego niby nie?", "Zastanowie się", "Lubisz mnie?", "Zgadzam się",
                        "Słucham?", "Tak", "Nie", "Kto pytał", "Ale kto pytał", "Ok, nie pytałem.", "Co lubisz jeść?", "Co robisz?", "Wszystkiego",
                        "Wszystko"]
            response = random.choice(responseList)
            await message.channel.send(response)

    # Sprawdzenie, czy wiadomość pochodzi z określonego kanału jeżeli wiadomość nie została wysłana przez cel odpowiada każdemu kto wyslał wiadomośc na konkretnym kanale
    elif message.channel.id == setChannelID:
        try:
            if message.attachments and message.content:
                # Obsługa wiadomości z tekstem i obrazem
                image_url = message.attachments[0].url
                image_response = generate_image_response(image_url)
                text_response = generate_response(message.content)
                response = f"Obraz: {image_response}\n\nTekst: {text_response}"
            elif message.attachments:
                # Obsługa obrazów
                image_url = message.attachments[0].url
                response = generate_image_response(image_url)
            else:
                # Generowanie odpowiedzi za pomocą OpenAI
                response = generate_response(message.content)

            # Odpowiedź na wiadomość (bez pingu to będzie na False)
            await message.reply(response, mention_author=True)
        except Exception as e: # W przypadku błędu poinformuj uzytkownika i spróbuj wysłać prywatną wiadomość do twórcy aplikacji z informacjami o błędzie oraz z linkiem do wiadomości która spowodowała błąd
            print(f"{e}")
            response = (f"Witaj {message.author.mention}, niestety wystąpił błąd!\nBłąd: Nie udało się wykonać polecenia lub Uzyskać/wysłać odpowiedzi.\n\n"
                        f"Wysłałem już szczegółowe informacje na temat błędu do <@{ownerID}> aby spróbował rozwiązać ten problem .\n"
                        "W ciąż jeszcze się uczę, dziekuje za wyrozumiałość .")
            await message.reply(response, mention_author=True)

            # Wysłanie wiadomości do właściciela z inforacjami o błędzie oraz z linkiem do wiadomości która spowodowała błąd
            try: #Próba przesłania danych o błędzie do własciciela aplikacji (w prywatnej wiadomości)
                owner = await client.fetch_user(ownerID)
                messageURL = message.jump_url
                await owner.send(f"Wystąpił błąd przy wykonywaniu komendy przez użytkownika {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}:\n```\n{e}\n```"
                                 f"\n\nLink do wiadomości która spowodowała błąd jest tutaj: [Kliknij tutaj aby przejść do wiadomości]({messageURL})")
            except: pass # Jak się nie uda to pass

# Uruchomienie bota
client.run(setTOKEN)


All critical data (OPENAI_API_KEY and TOKEN) are in the .env file. I don't upload this data here.
